# JetBrains PhpStorm code formatter problem

Tags: phpstorm

I have problem with phpStorm and code formatter

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    if ($x > 5) {
        echo "bar";
    }
    return
            "string";
}
```

where can i change that formater will change

```
if ($x > 5) {
            echo "bar";
        }
```

to

```
if ($x > 5) 
{
            echo "bar";
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings` | `Code Style` | `PHP` | `Wrapping and Braces`, `Braces placement`
`Other`: **Next line**.